# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error when running web scraper program

Tags: java, web, screen-scraping, jsoup

I'm fairly new to web scraping and have limited knowledge on Java.

Every time I run this code, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at sws.SWS.scrapeTopic(SWS.java:38)
    at sws.SWS.main(SWS.java:26)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

My code is:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class SWS
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        scrapeTopic("wiki/Python");

    }

    public static void scrapeTopic(String url)
    {
        String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/" + url);



        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        String contentText = doc.select("#mw-content-text > p").first().text();

        System.out.println(contentText);


    }


    public static String getUrl(String Url)
    {
        URL urlObj = null;

        try 
        {
            urlObj = new URL(Url);

        }

        catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("The url was malformed");

            return "";
        }


        URLConnection urlCon = null;

        BufferedReader in = null;

        String outputText = "";

        try
        {
            urlCon = urlObj.openConnection();

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream()));
             String line = "";

             while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
             {
                 outputText += line;

             }

             in.close();
        }

         catch(IOException e)
         {
             System.out.println("There was a problem connecting to the url");

             return "";

         }

        return outputText;



    }

}
```

I've been staring at my screen for sometime now and in need of help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line is `SWS.java:38`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code:

```
 String contentText = doc.select("#mw-content-text > p").first().text()
```

If `doc.select("#mw-content-text > p")`  doesn't find any element that match the query and returns an ***empty*** element calling `first()` on such element should give a `NullPointerException`.

check the jsoup document page of [Element.select](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29) and [Elements.first()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#first%28%29)

Comment: A reasonable possibility, though as noted in my answer, it didn't happen for me when running the OP's code.  Don't know who downvoted or why, but have an upvote!

Comment: Thank you for the support. Probably for your case, it is reading the html document successfully, that means OP is probably failing on `urlConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
doc.select("#mw-content-text > p").first().text();
```

Your doc.select obviously dont find anything, so it returns null. You then call `first()` method on null and thats why it ends with error.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: Upvoted to compensate unwarranted downvote.  Though actually, select doesn't return null but an empty element.  Still a reasonable suspicion.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me exactly as it is.

For the purpose of debugging and diagnosing whether the possible errors noted by other answers, you'd likely do well to use some temporary variables and step through the code in a debugger.

```
public static void scrapeTopic(String url)
{
    String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/" + url);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements select = doc.select("#mw-content-text > p");
    Element first = select.first();
    String contentText = first.text();

    System.out.println(contentText);
}
```