# Unusual output when using Jsoup in Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am getting this output when trying to use Jsoup to extract text from Wikipedia:

I dont have enough rep to post pictures as I am new to this site but its basically like this:

```
[]{k[]q[]f[]d[]d  etc..
```

Here is part of my code:

```
public static void scrapeTopic(String url)

{
    String html = getUrl("http://www.wikipedia.org/" + url);



    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    String contentText = doc.select("*").first().text();

    System.out.println(contentText);


}
```

It appears to get all the information but in the wrong format!

I appreciate any help given
Thanks in advance

Comment: Jsoup doesn't return pictures but text, and surely you can post more of the text returned.

Comment: When I copy and paste it In here it changes into something completely different. That's why I tried to upload an image of the output

Comment: please post the returned text

Comment: and what does your getUrl method do?

Comment: And why the `doc.select("*").first().text();`? What exactly are you trying to extract with that?

Comment: @Hovercraft, his getUrl opens a conenction and fetch the page. [check his last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337516/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-when-running-w/19337571#19337571), he asked half an hour ago.

Comment: @Sage: OK, thanks. I usually use `Jsoup.connect(...).get()` for this.

Comment: yup [Jsoup.connect("url").get()](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) is much simpler.

Comment: �}k��q�g�h6c��y����(�re  <--This is what the output looks like when I C+P it in here.

Comment: @Craig, ok give us the `url` you are trying to fetch, otherwise we are not being able to help you

Comment: "http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python" is the URL that I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestion for you. While fetching general webpage, which doesn't require HTTP header's field to be set like *cookie*, *user-agent* just call:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("givenURL").get();
```

This function read the webpage using a GET request. When you are selecting element using `*`, it returns any element, that is all the element of the document. Hence, calling `doc.select("*").first()` is returning the `#root` element. Try printing it to see:

```
System.out.println(doc.select("*").first().tagName()); // #root
System.out.println(doc.select("*").first());  // will print the whole document, 
System.out.println(doc); //print the whole document, the above action is pointless
System.out.println(doc.select("*").first()==doc); 
               // check whither they are equal, and it will print TRUE
```

I am assuming that you are just playing around to learn about this API, although [`selector`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) is much powerful,  but a good start should be trying general document manipulation function e.g., `doc.getElementsByTag()`.

However, in my local machine, i was successful to fetch the Document and parsing it using your `getURL()` function !!